# Getting the value between two points on a curve

Tags: php, math, algebra

I didn't pay attention much in math class, and this problem is giving me so much trouble. I'm trying to create a function for estimating pricing based on quantities, on a logistic curve. I haven't decided on the steepness or the midpoint yet, I was going to play with it until I got it where I like it, but the start point is 1 and the end point is 7.5

So basically the function would solve: if a quantity of 12 has a value of 1 on the curve, and a quantity of 500 has a value of 7.5 on the curve then how do I get the value of a quantity of 48?

I've been doing research all day on curve fittings and all these algebraic formulas but converting them to a programming algorithm is proving difficult, and not knowing all the right terms is not helping my search. Any help is much appreciated!!!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There's no right answer as to *how* the price should vary with the quantity.   The answer really is: you can fit any curve you like between the two points, then it's easy to compute.  But until you decide you can't really reverse engineer an unknown function in PHP.

Comment: well, you don't need us to relevant the wheel and fitting those formulas too .

Comment: There are infinite curves equations that owns two points but only one straight line equation: https://www.mathsisfun.com/straight-line-graph-calculate.html

Comment: I edited the post to reflect my question better. In my frustration I forgot to mention that it's a logistic curve, if that makes the question easier to answer.

Comment: Without knowing the midpoint and the maximum value (and I believe the steepness of the curve), you're still at an infinite number of potential functions afaik.

Comment: see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8213/logistic-function-passing-through-two-points

Comment: For a logistic curve with max value L, steepness k, and midpoint m, the equation is L / ( 1 + exp( k ( x - m) ). That's an equation with three unknowns. To be able to specify the three unknowns uniquely you would need three points. The question only has two points mentioned so there is not a unique solution. You could specify some aditional constraint or choose one of the unknowns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll first need to decide what kind of function you want to fit to your points. I'll assume, for this example, that you wish to do a linear fit. That means you'll be looking for a line that passes through the two points you gave. The end goal is to have a function y = mx + b where x and y are the variables and m and b are parameters that you calculate from your given points. In your case, x will be quantity. Once you have found numbers for m and b then you just code up a function that returns y when you input x.

Your two points (that the line must pass through) are (x,y)=(12,1) and (500, 7.5). The way you find m and b are to treat m and b as the variables and plug in the two given points and solve for m and b. Thus, you want to solve these two simultaneous equations:
1 = m*12 + b
7.5 = m*500 + b

One way to do this is to solve the first equation for b: b = 1 - m*12.
Then plug that into the second equation, which is to say, replace b in the second equation with (1 - m*12) then solve for m, like this:
7.5 = m*500 + 1 - m*12 which gives m = 6.5/488
Now that you have m, you plug it back into the first equation and solve for b: 1 = 12*6.5/488 + b or b = 1 - 12*6.5/488. These don't come out as nice clean numbers but they are approximately b = 0.84 and m = 0.0133.

Check your work to see that y = 0.0133*x + 0.84 does, in fact, pass through your two given points. That is, if x is 12 you should compute y is approximately 1 and if x is 500, you should compute y is approximately 7.5. Since I rounded the values of m and b this won't be exact. You can get it more exact by specifying m in your function as 6.5/488 and similarly for b (let the computer do the math) or by just using more digits.

If you want to fit a curved line to these points, you have to first decide what kind of function you will fit (quadratic, exponential, square root, logarithm, other power law, etc).